# How do I keep horizontal links in place with slideToggle and responsive design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a grid of product logos using responsive design so that they adjust to screen width.  For every row of logos, I want the info about them to all be different, but when they slide down to appear in the same position.

[image: Here's what I'm going for]

However, when I try to accomplish this it shifts my logos all over the place. 
Here is what I have tried on [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pberard2002/5sw59e66/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var clicked = true;
$('.one').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next('.two').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your html and jquery a bit

https://jsfiddle.net/5sw59e66/11/

```
<div class="products-container">
    <div class="one" data-id="p1">Click me</div>
    <div class="one" data-id="p2">Click me</div>
    <div class="one" data-id="p3">Click me</div>
    <div class="one" data-id="p4">Click me</div>
</div>  
<div class="products-description-container">
    <h3 class="two" id="p1">First product description</h3>
    <h3 class="two" id="p2">Second product description</h3>
    <h3 class="two" id="p3">Third product description</h3>
    <h3 class="two" id="p4">Fourth product description</h3>
</div>
```

This structure makes more sense for what you want to do

Comment: That's a neat idea.  However, and this is probably on me for not being the best with descriptions, I need the content from the description class to appear directly under whichever row the logo is in.  So let's say I have 20 logos in a 4x5 grid at x screen size. if I click on the top left logo, the drop down will happen beneath the 4 logos in the first row. If I expand the screen size to where my grid is now 5x4, and I click on the top right logo, I need the info to drop down beneath the 5 logos on the top row. Does that make any sense, or am I just rambling?

Comment: no you're not rambling, but i think that that's going to complicate things a bit more.. i'll try to think about one solution, and hopefully someone else comes with some ideas!

Comment: Oh it definitely complicates things. Thank you.